# Advanced pointer typecasting in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, assembly, casting

I've searched all the net, but I didn't find any thing.

I want to know how it makes sense for example when you type :

```
 char *buffer = "Everything! such as shellcodes"

 int ret;

 ret = (int *)& ret +2 ;

 (*ret) = (int)buffer;
```

Or when you use :

```
(* (void(*) ()) shellcode)();
```

Which shellcode is char pointer.

I know & gives the address of a variable but I don't know the

```
(int *) then address of something
```

I think it overwrites the EIP.
but the second code what does it actually do ?

I know maybe it not be good question, but I want to know how to get deep concept about pointers and their typecasting.

Would you mind giving me the concepts of the matter by an article or book or ... .
I want to learn this to understand and write such a thing by oneself.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Your first block of code definitely won't compile. Second may compile but won't run on any reasonably recent system.

Comment: Make sure to copy/paste the code snippet rather than typing it by hand, otherwise your question becomes invalid.

Comment: I'm So sorry, but i just wanted to know are there any article or any book to explain advanced typecasting in C ? it's whole of my question :)

Comment: @user3679015 Check the [c++ tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b?sort=frequent). There's a whole list of books and links.

Comment: Looks to me like you ran across some exploit code or other cute trickery and are trying to figure out how it does what it does. If you want a sensible answer, a bit of context would help. Otherwise expect to get closed.

Comment: I admit that the question is a little bit messy. BUT it is still reasonable and helpful! I don't know why people downvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory simply contains bytes of data. It is up to you how you interpret this data.

Your buffer may be interpreted as `int`. For example:

```
char buffer[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int number = *(int *)buffer;
```

Running the code on an Intel x86 processor would result in `number` having the value of `0x04030201`, as integers are stored as 32bit (4 bytes) little-endian buffers.

Your buffer can also be interpreted as code. The C code `return 5;` may be compiled into the following x86 assembly code:

```
mov eax, 5
retn
```

This code looks in the memory as `B8 05 00 00 00 C3`

So let's look on the following example:

```
char buffer[] = {0xb8, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0xc3};
int number = ((int (*)())(buffer))();
```

Running this code on an Intel x86 processor (assuming you compile this code without security checks that prevent the execution of data buffers) would result in `number` having the value of 5; The code casts the pointer to `buffer` into a pointer to a function with the signature `int func_name()` and then executes it.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you a lot!)